# killing multi-threaded operations with database read and writes

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, hibernate, exception

I have a multi threaded java process running  with the 2 db transactions as follows:

```
.
.
dbop1();
.
.
.
dbop2();
.
.
```

when I kill the process(using kill on linux), database might loss integrity because the program might terminate in between dbop1() and dbop2().
if there a way to catch the kill signal and then terminate gracefully? for example, if the kill is in between, I would like to still finish dbop2() and then terminate.

I'm hesitant to make the 2 db transactions in a single transaction because of performance concerns.
and I'm assuming that if the kill happens during a db  transaction the data would not be corrupt, is this true?
further more dbop1() and dbop2() are hibernate wrappers like the following:

```
    try{
            beginTransaction();
            getSession().save(obj);
            //sessionFactory.openSession().save(obj);
            commitTransaction();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

            rollbackTransaction();
            throw e;
        }finally{
            closeSession(); 
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29

Answer (score 1):

As you already mention, the correct approach here is to put both db statements inside one transaction, as anything else is very likely to have integrity issues.  It may depend on your particular use case, but integrity concerns are usually far more important than any performance concerns you may have here.

The reasons for this extend beyond the application being killed via `kill` since the second db statement could have an exception, the application could crash in between the two of them, or the server / networking could have an issue, etc etc.  So best practices is definitely to put both statements into one transaction.

Now, saying all of that, it is possible to block a kill statement depending on the kill level, perhaps by registering a shutdown hook that waits (or blocks) until both statements have completed.  I would not recommend this, however, as a `kill -9` would skip this entirely as would the other possibilities mentioned above.

E.g. (for completeness only, as I really do not recommend the below code at all). 
Using a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` somehow shared via `sharedState` (maybe set into the shutdown hook below or it could be a singleton if you really desire).

```
Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run()
    {
        sharedState.rwl.writeLock().lock();
        System.out.println("We are shutting down!");
        // Hopefully holding this lock does not prevent our shutdown
        // I.e. no other thread needs it to complete gracefully
    }
}
```

and

```
try
{
    sharedState.rwl.readLock().lock();
    dbOp1;
    dbOp2;
} finally
{
    sharedState.rwl.readLock().unlock();
}
```

where `sharedState` represents some mechanism whereby you have shared the rwl between the shutdown hook and your code running the db operations.